# Use cURL Multi, but still not asynchronous

Tags: php, curl

I use curl_multi to scrap several site, and I hope it will run asynchronously or parallel so it will not other to finish first.

I use jquery to trigger xmlhttprequest to php.

But what I get it still run synchronous, I dont know what is wrong whether my code or my PC specification (I run local server use core-i5 and 4GB memory)

This is my jquery code

```
function ajaxSearchFlight(agent)
{
    var depart_from = $("#depart_from").val();
    var arrive_to = $("#arrive_to").val();
    var depart_date = $("#depart_date").val();
    var adult = $("#adult").val();
    var child = $("#child").val();
    var infant = $("#infant").val();

    depart_date = new Date(depart_date);
    var year = depart_date.getFullYear();
    var month = depart_date.getMonth() + 1;
    var date = depart_date.getDate();
    if(month < 10)
    {
        month = "0"+month;
    }
    if(date < 10)
    {
        date = "0"+date;
    }
    depart_date = year+"-"+month+"-"+date;  

    if(agent == "all")
    {
        findflight_tesflight1(depart_from, arrive_to, depart_date, adult, child, infant);
        findflight_tesflight2(depart_from, arrive_to, depart_date, adult, child, infant);
    }
}

function findflight_tesflight1(depart_from, arrive_to, depart_date, adult, child, infant)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '<?php echo Url::toRoute("flight/getliveflighttesflight1"); ?>?depart_from='+depart_from+'&arrive_to='+arrive_to+'&date_format_start='+depart_date+'&adults_pass='+adult+'&children_pass='+child+'&infants_pass='+infant, true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4) 
        {
            if(this.status == 200)
            {
                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);   
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.send(); 
}

function findflight_tesflight2(depart_from, arrive_to, depart_date, adult, child, infant)
{       
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '<?php echo Url::toRoute("flight/getliveflighttesflight2"); ?>?depart_from='+depart_from+'&arrive_to='+arrive_to+'&date_format_start='+depart_date+'&adults_pass='+adult+'&children_pass='+child+'&infants_pass='+infant, true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState == 4) 
        {
            if(this.status == 200)
            {
                var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.send(); 
}
```

and this is PHP code

```
class FlightController extends \yii\web\Controller
{   
    protected $mh;

    public function beforeAction($event)
    {
        $this->mh = curl_multi_init();
        return parent::beforeAction($event);
    }   

    public function actionGetliveflighttesflight1($depart_from, $arrive_to, $date_format_start, $adult, $child, $infant)
    {               
        $url = 'https://api.flight2.com/en/flight/';                        

        $response_tes = "";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);    

        curl_multi_add_handle($this->mh,$ch);

        do {
            while(($execrun = curl_multi_exec($this->mh, $running)) == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
            if($execrun != CURLM_OK)
                break;
            while($done = curl_multi_info_read($this->mh)) {
                $info = curl_getinfo($done['handle']);
                if ($info['http_code'] == 200)  {
                    $output = curl_multi_getcontent($done['handle']);
                    $response_tes = $output;
                    curl_multi_remove_handle($this->mh, $done['handle']);
                } else {
                }
            }
        } while ($running);     

        try {
            return $response_tes;
        } catch (Exception $e) {            
        }               
    }

    public function actionGetliveflighttesflight2($depart_from, $arrive_to, $date_format_start, $adult, $child, $infant)    
    {                   
        $url = 'https://www.flight1.com/ajax?d='.$depart_from.'&a='.$arrive_to.'&date='.$date_format_start.'&adult='.$adult.'&child='.$child.'&infant='.$infant;                    

        $response_tes = "";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip'); 

        curl_multi_add_handle($this->mh,$ch);

        do {
            while(($execrun = curl_multi_exec($this->mh, $running)) == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
            if($execrun != CURLM_OK)
                break;
            while($done = curl_multi_info_read($this->mh)) {
                $info = curl_getinfo($done['handle']);
                if ($info['http_code'] == 200)  {
                    $output = curl_multi_getcontent($done['handle']);
                    $response_tes = $output;
                    curl_multi_remove_handle($this->mh, $done['handle']);
                } else {
                }
            }
        } while ($running);         

        try {       
            return $response_tes;   
        } catch (Exception $e) {            
        }       
    }
}
```

Please help, I need to make it async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it set up right kinda, but your logic is wrong. It looks like your only ever sending information to your php scripts for one url at a time.  You might as well just use a regular curl request.

Curl_multi is designed to fetch the data for multiple urls asynchronously.  So that being said, you will want to feed the functions multiple urls.

So here is an example of how to set up a good curl_multi routine.  You will have to adapt this to your own code, but it's a good road map.  Hope it helps.

```
function multi_thread_curl($urlArray, $optionArray, $nThreads) {

  //Group your urls into groups/threads.
  $curlArray = array_chunk($urlArray, $nThreads, $preserve_keys = true);

  //Iterate through each batch of urls.
  foreach($curlArray as $threads) {

      //Create your cURL resources.
      foreach($threads as $key=>$value) {

      ${ch . $key} = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array(${ch . $key}, $optionArray); //Set your main curl options.
        curl_setopt(${ch . $key}, CURLOPT_URL, $value); //Set url.

        }

      //Create the multiple cURL handler.
      $mh = curl_multi_init();

      //Add the handles.
      foreach($threads as $key=>$value) {

      curl_multi_add_handle($mh, ${ch . $key});

      }

      $active = null;

      //execute the handles.
      do {

      $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);

      } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

      while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {

          if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
              do {

                  $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);

              } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
          }

      }

      //Get your data and close the handles.
      foreach($threads as $key=>$value) {

      $results[$key] = curl_multi_getcontent(${ch . $key});

      curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, ${ch . $key});

      }

      //Close the multi handle exec.
      curl_multi_close($mh);

  }


  return $results;

}


//Add whatever options here. The CURLOPT_URL is left out intentionally.
//It will be added in later from the url array.  
$optionArray = array(

  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER    => FALSE,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT           => 10

);

//Create an array of your urls.
$urlArray = array(

 'www.example.com/index.php?id=1',
 'www.example.com/index.php?id=2',
 'www.example.com/index.php?id=3',
 'www.example.com/index.php?id=4'

);

//Play around with this number and see what works best.
//This is how many urls it will try to do at one time.
$nThreads = 20;  


$results = multi_thread_curl($urlArray, $optionArray, $nThreads);
```